# Step by step log information in PSsession

Tags: powershell-3.0

Could you please help me record each step of the script in a log file as I am deleting the IIS log files. I need to record the files that have been deleted in a log file. How to do that? I am a beginner in Powershell

```
foreach ($Server in $Servers) {
 try { 
    $inetpubDuration = (get-date).AddDays(-4) 
    $ccmduration= (get-date).AddDays(-92) 
    $keep= 3 
    $IISfiles= Get-ChildItem -Path \\$Server\C$\Users\eedc_a_miruday\Desktop\Testlog\*.log | where {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $inetpubDuration} 
    if ($files.Count -gt $keep) { 
      $IISfiles | Remove-Item $message = "$(Get-Date) : Deleting File $IISfiles" $message | Out-File -append "C:\Test\status.log" 
    }
```

Comment: We need more context, post your script, or what you have tried so far.